# Position of SCNode Object infront of Camera With ARKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to add Bullet in my Scene with ARKit.

Here is what i have done to add bullet in my Scene

```
{

SCNNode* systemNode = [SCNNode new];
SCNSphere *sphere = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:0.01];
systemNode.geometry = sphere;
systemNode.renderingOrder = 1;
SCNPhysicsShape *shape  = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:sphere options:nil];
systemNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:shape];
systemNode.physicsBody.mass = 0.05;
systemNode.physicsBody.friction = 0.01;
systemNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
SCNScene *modelScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"Cartridge45.scn" inDirectory:@"art.scnassets/models" options:nil];

Bullet *bulletNode = [Bullet new];
bulletNode = (Bullet *) [modelScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"cartridge" recursively:YES];
bulletNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
bulletNode.renderingOrder = 1;
Bullet *bulletNode1 = [Bullet new];
bulletNode1 = (Bullet *) [modelScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"cartridge_1" recursively:YES];
bulletNode1.scale = SCNVector3Make(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
bulletNode1.renderingOrder = 1;

SCNVector3 min, max;
[bulletNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];
CGFloat collisionCapsuleRadius = 0.01;
CGFloat collisionCapsuleHeight = 0.1;
NSLog(@"El Bouncing Box. El min es collisionCapsuleRadius:%f collisionCapsuleHeight:%f", collisionCapsuleRadius, collisionCapsuleHeight);

SCNNode *bColNode = [SCNNode node];
NSString *nameCube = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BulletB%d", rand()];
bColNode.name =nameCube;
bColNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 1.2);// a bit too high to not hit the floor
bColNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:[SCNCapsule capsuleWithCapRadius:collisionCapsuleRadius height:collisionCapsuleHeight] options:nil]];
bColNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryBullet;
bColNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryInvader;
[systemNode addChildNode:bColNode];

ARFrame *frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame;
SCNVector3 direction;
SCNVector3 position;

if (frame != nil) {
    SCNMatrix4 mat = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(frame.camera.transform);
    direction = SCNVector3Make(mat.m41, mat.m42, mat.m43);
    position = SCNVector3Make(mat.m31*-1, mat.m32*-1, mat.m33*-1);
}
else {
    direction = SCNVector3Make(0,0,-0.11);
    position = SCNVector3Make(0,0,-0.1);
}
systemNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0);
bulletNode.position = position;
bulletNode1.position = position;
systemNode.name=@"bullet";
[systemNode addChildNode:bulletNode];
[systemNode addChildNode:bulletNode1];

SCNMatrix4 transform = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(frame.camera.transform);
    SCNVector4 force = SCNVector4Make(0, 0,-5, 0);
    SCNVector3 rotatedForce = [self to3:[self multiplyVector:transform :force]];
    [systemNode.physicsBody applyForce:rotatedForce impulse:YES];
    [self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:systemNode];

}
```

The bullet is getting added at same direction disregards of view of camera in real world.

Comment: You are always placing the bullet at (0,0,0). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @orangenkopf - I tried with mat.m41 m42 m43 too but result was same

Comment: Are you experiencing this while testing in the simulator?

Comment: @ChrisHaze - No , i am testing with 6s

Comment: Try some logging and check wether your position gets updated correctly.

Comment: @orangenkopf - Yes node positions are getting updated

Comment: Node position : -0.186045 ----0.181632---0.965607
2017-09-11 18:31:54.291467+0530 InvaderShooter[1555:148347] Node position : -0.123350 ----0.190902---0.973828
2017-09-11 18:31:55.095557+0530 InvaderShooter[1555:148347] Node position : -0.137488 ----0.176105---0.974723
2017-09-11 18:31:55.660413+0530 InvaderShooter[1555:148347] Node position : -0.135556 ----0.158906---0.977943
2017-09-11 18:31:56.160095+0530 InvaderShooter[1555:148347] Node position : -0.137585 ----0.148222---0.979337